# Convert Textfield (hours and minutes / HH:mm) to Datetime (only hours / HH)

Tags: c#, datetime

Since i got really fast and good answers last time i'd like to ask you all for help one more time.

I have a string (taken from a textfield in an access mdb) which consists of a Time value (HH:mm).

Now i want to take this string and put it into a datetime picker. 
But here is the tricky part: 
I Need to only get the hours shown in the datetime picker since i will use this field to do more calculatings later.

So if the string is for example "13:27" the datetime picker should only Show "13:00".

I tried it with the following Code but unfortunately with this i get the error date 01.01.0001 13:00:00.

```
dateTimePicker2.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();    

string s = dateTimePicker2.Text.Split(':')[0];
                double ss = Convert.ToDouble(s);
                TimeSpan TS = TimeSpan.FromHours(ss);
                DateTime DT = DateTime.MinValue.Add(TS);

                dateTimePicker2.Text = Convert.ToString(DT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dateTimePicker2.Text = DT.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var curr =Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
string hour = curr.ToString("HH:00");
dateTimePicker1.Text = hour;
```

Comment: Please add a short explication to say why this works

Answer (score 0):

> i get the error date 01.01.0001 13:00:00.

That is  because of the line

```
DateTime DT = DateTime.MinValue.Add(TS);
```

Replace that with DateTime DT = DateTime.Now.Add(TS);
you should get current date along with your intended hour.